# how to solve the ` Component should be written as a pure function ` error in eslint-react?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

```
class Option extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClickOption = this.handleClickOption.bind(this);
  }
  handleClickOption() {
    // some code
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this.handleClickOption}>{this.props.option}</li>
    );
  }
}
```

I use [eslint-config-airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb) to check the above code and it show me an error msg like `Component should be written as a pure function` .

So how to change the above component to pure function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

React 0.14 introduced pure function components.

This should be the preferred option for all stateless components.

```js
function Option({ onClick, option }) {
    return (
        <li onClick={onClick}>
            {option}
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: There's a dfference though in that the click handler is part of the component in the question.

Comment: Most times you're better off defining the click handler at a higher level. Alternatively, you could make it a separate function in the same file.

Answer (score 19):

In ES6 you might do something similar to this:

```js
const Options = (props) => {

    const handleClickOption = () => {
        // some code
    }

    return (
        <li onClick={handleClickOption}>{props.myOptionsListItem}</li>
    );
};

Options.propTypes = {
    // validate props
};

export default Options;
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your particular solution, but more as a general response to this type of coding style: I don't get it. Why create a new `handleClickOption` every time your component is supposed to render, instead of a prototypical object that will all share the same function reference but use a different context for each execution? Seems like bloat for the JS engine...

Comment: its working fine for me :D i vote for this @John Meyer

Comment: You reference "Option", then export "Options" is that right?

Answer (score 16):

The Stateless functional components will benefit from future React performance optimizations specific to these components.
Here's the way we can write component as pure function:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 id="heading">Hello ReactJS </h2>
      <header />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

However if you want to write component in ES6 style, you still can do but in this case the eslint error need to be removed (if you are using eslint).
The following change in .eslintrc file

E.G:

```js
"rules": {
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": "off"
}
```

Then here ES6 style component you can write with eslint enable:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header className="header">
        <h1>Home page</h1>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 8):

It means you declare stateful component in react without construct. The scenario can be like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Something extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <div>Your classes</div>
      )
   }
}
```

Above code is wrong so the right code should be like this

```
class Something extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.props = props;
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <div>Your classes</div>
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Does anybody knows how to call a component specific prop inside of the passed click-function.

E.g.

```js
function ElementRow({onClick, element, key}) {
  return (
    <tr key={key}>
      <td><a href="#" onClick={onClick}>Delete</a></td>
      <td>
        ...
      <td>{ element.first } { element.last }</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Inside of the `onClick` function I need the `element.id`. I am looking for a solution without using `bind()`

I know how to get it work with `React.createClass` or `extend React.Component` but not written as a pure function.

**Edit**: Found a solution but I am not sure if it's a code smell. :)

```js
function ElementRow({ onClick, element, key }) {
  const _onClick = (e) => {
    onClick(e, element.id);
  };

  return (
    <tr key={key}>
      <td><a href="#" onClick={_onClick}>Delete</a></td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>{ element.first } { element.last }</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Comment: In this instance you might as well inline the function `onClick={(event) => onClick(event, element.id)}`. Alternatively consider defining the onClick event at a higher level (i.e. the parent component). In future, if you have a question, please start a new thread rather than tacking a question onto an existing one.

Comment: you're right, next time i will start a new thread, wasnt sure about it. in this case the onClick is passed through props from a parent component. i think its worth to start a new thread with a full and more descriptive example.